# Find which side of square circle is on

Tags: c, geometry, 2d, game-development

I'm building some collision detection into my 2D game, and I've got a method to test the collision and find the depth and normal of the collision, but I'm stuck on trying to figure out on which side the collision occured.

The CirclePosition and the RectPosition here are the center of the shapes. I am using OpenGL so positive Y = down and negative Y = up.

The objects I'm testing with are a circle and a square. These shapes are axis aligned.

So my question is:

**How can I detect which side of the square is the circle has hit?**

This is the code I have so far:

```
enum side {
    SideLeft,
    SideRight,
    SideAbove,
    SideBelow,
};

typedef struct {
    int Collided;
    float Depth;
    float2 Normal;
    side Side;
} collision;

collision CircleRectIntersection(float2 CirclePosition, float Radius, float2 RectPosition, float2 Size) {
    float Top = RectPosition.Y - (Size.Y / 2);
    float Left = RectPosition.X - (Size.X / 2);
    float Bottom = RectPosition.Y + (Size.Y / 2);
    float Right = RectPosition.X + (Size.X / 2);
    
    float ExtentX = Size.X / 2;
    float ExtentY = Size.Y / 2;
    
    float2 N = RectPosition - CirclePosition;
    float2 Closest = N;
    Closest.X = Clamp(-ExtentX, ExtentX, Closest.X);
    Closest.Y = Clamp(-ExtentY, ExtentY, Closest.Y);
    
    bool Inside = false;
    if(N == Closest) {
        Inside = true;
        if(fabs(N.X) > fabs(N.Y)) {
            if(Closest.X > 0) Closest.X = ExtentX;
            else Closest.X = -ExtentX;
        }
        else {
            if(Closest.Y > 0) Closest.Y = ExtentY;
            else Closest.Y = -ExtentY;
        }
    }
    
    float2 Normal = N - Closest;
    float D = LengthSquare(Normal);
    float R = Radius;
    
    D = sqrt(D);
    
    collision C;
    if(D > R && !Inside) {
        C.Collided = 0;
        return C;
    }
    
    if(Inside) C.Normal = -N;
    else C.Normal = N;
    
    C.Depth = R - D;
    
    return C;
}
```

And here is some example code of how I would expect this to work:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   float2 RectPosition = float2(100, 100);
   float2 RectSize = float2(100, 100);

   float2 CirclePosition = float2(150, 100);
   float2 Radius = 20.0f;

   collision C = CircleRectIntersection(CirclePosition, Radius, RectPosition, RectSize);
  
   // here I would expect C.Side to be side.Right, as the circle is to the right of the rect
}
```

Comment: It is unclear if you ask about designing an algorithm or how to implement a known algorithm in your funtion. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Add a `main` function that calls `CircleRectIntersection` with hard-coded input and prints the result to demonstrate your problem. Show the actual and expected output and both good and bad cases. Or explain what exactly is wrong/missing in your function.

Comment: What do you man by "the circle is on"? You mean which side it has hit? As a circle may be on two sides at once. E.g. on which side is that circle: https://postimg.cc/5XGZJFTk It doesn't hit any side but it is on two sides at once.

Comment: @Mecki sorry, which side the circle has hit.

Comment: Note that circle-side collision is very different from circle-corner collision. It gives you 8 individual cases rather than 4.

Comment: replace `sqrt(D) > R` with `D > R * R`. It is likely going to be "a bit" faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smallest of the four distances, two distances from `CirclePosition.X` to { Left, Right } and two distances `CirclePosition.Y` to { Top, Bottom } will give you which Rectangle side was hit.